# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds not working

Tags: sound

I usually disable the annoying system sounds (such those beeps when you reach the end the pager and move forward) with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds false
```

It should disable the "Volume level" in this picture:

[image]

However, it is not disabling it.

System information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: Inspiron 5570 
Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic 
Uptime: 4 hours, 47 mins 
Packages: 1764 (dpkg), 11 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: GNOME 42.9 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: kitty 
CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 530/535 / 620/625 Mobile 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 1526MiB / 2272MiB
```